# Google sheet script - copy row values to last used row

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

basicly i need help to copy content of row 2 in that case range A2:AC2 ( not a problem if it copy paste the entire row 2) to last used row

i already have a script to appendRow to last unused row, what i want is to not manually have to edit that in case i need to update those values

found a script to get last used row, but it returns row number

```
function getLRI() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Fund');

  var lr = getLastRowIndex(ss,'A1:AC');
  
  Logger.log (lr);

}


function getLastRowIndex(sheet,rangeString) {

  var rng = sheet.getRange(rangeString).getValues();
  
  var lrIndex;
  
  for ( var i = rng.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    lrIndex = i;
    
    if(!rng[i].every(function(c){ return c == ""; })){
      break;
    
    }
    
  }
  
  return lrIndex + 1;
  
}
```

output of `Logger.log (lr)`;

```
[20-10-30 16:35:33:460 BRT] 47.0
```

so i get the row number correct, but not managing to figure out how to make `.getRange()` and `.setValues` work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

The solution is much more simpler than you think.

- You don't need to create a custom function to calculate the last row with content in your sheet, because there is already a built in function that does this job provided by Google and this is [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).
- The following script will get the data in the range `A2:AC2` using [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and it will set the values after the last row with content using [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Fund');
  const data = sh.getRange(2,1,1,29).getValues(); // A2:AC2
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: thanks, simpler than i was trying, worked as i wanted to edit last used row after removing +1 in sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1

Comment: i know the script i posted does extra checks, checking rows botton up, isblank, skips in case cells contain formulas not values, but the end result of it is row nunber, could it be used in anyway? im asking to learn, anyway thanks a lot buddy

Comment: I guess you can do that: `const data = sh.getRange(2,1,1,29).getValues(); // A2:AC2
sh.getRange(lr,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);`

Comment: thanks a lot, with tweaks ad some experiments i learned more about scripts and java with your answer and google more than i asked here, keep up for sure you help lots of ppl